# Jquery Autocomeplete Get Selected value call javascript function

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I had a previous version of jquery.autocomplete and whenever i selected an item i am able to have another function parse the selected value.

now i am using the v1.1 plugin found at
http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/
and i need to know which function i can use so i can parse the selected value.

thanks.

```
function Itemselected(li) {

    $.ajax({
    url: 'default2.aspx?w='+li.value,
    success: function(data) {
         //more code here   
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always check the documentation, it's linked from the plugin main page:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

`result` method is doing this, if I understand your question correctly.